# How to Dynamically update Youtube Player videoID

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a js function that returns a random VideoID from a channel.  I want to dynamically insert this ID into the youtubeAPI's videoID parameter.

```
// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: <<INSERT RETURN OF FUNCTION HERE>>
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba utilizando esta linea :)

player.loadVideoById("id_video");

Comment: Normally you also don't need to define an initial `videoId`

Comment: Welcome! Please note that the [policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) is that [questions and answers need to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange).